# Не работает сценарий

Tags: php

Здраствуйте, мне нужна помощь.
Есть вот такая форма:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Make Me Elvis - Add Email</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
  <body>
 <img src="blankface.jpg" width="161" height="350" alt="" style="float:right" />
 <img name="elvislogo" src="elvislogo.gif" width="229" height="32" border="0"      alt="Make Me Elvis" />
 <p>Enter your first name, last name, and email to be added to the <strong>Make Me Elvis</strong> mailing list.</p>
 <form method="post" action="addemail.php">
   <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
   <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />
   <label for="email">Email:</label>
   <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

И есть сценарий:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Make Me Elvis - Add Email</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
  $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'elvis_store')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

  $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
  $last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO email_list (first_name, last_name, email)  VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database.');

  echo 'Customer added.';

  mysqli_close($dbc);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Когда выполняешь форму браузер отображает просто пустую страницу без ошибок, и без текста, хотя по идее должен вносить данные из формы в БД. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 1. сделай echo $query; и посмотри что за запрос получается. Попробуй выполнить получившийся запрос в phpmyadmin. 
2. Никогда не вставляй в базу напрямую из поста, валидируй поля.

Comment: @meboban лучше bind использовать.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь, но как я понял проблема была в том что пшп код вообще не обрабатывался, то ли я не правильно создал каталог в денвере, или по другой неизвестной мне причине, попробую разобраться, сейчас все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы еще посоветовал делать проверку на добавление в базу при помощи `mysql_insert_id()`, а уже при условии успешного добавления выводить 'Customer added.'